# Google Home Increase/Decrease Temperature Json Issue

Tags: json, actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

my device (named as the bedroom) is set to 26 and it's in cool mode.
when I ask my google home "hey google, increase bedroom temperature by 1".
JSON I am receiving from google home is posted below. According to this JSON, set the mode to heat and set the temperature to 26.

I am 100% sure it was working perfectly last week.It was sending me JSON to set only temperature.

```
"inputs": [{
"intent": "action.devices.EXECUTE",
"payload": {
  "commands": [
    {
      "execution": [
        {
          "params": {
            "thermostatMode": "heat"
          },
          "command": "action.devices.commands.ThermostatSetMode"
        },
        {
          "params": {
            "thermostatTemperatureSetpoint": 26
          },
          "command": "action.devices.commands.ThermostatTemperatureSetpoint"
        }
      ],
      "devices": [
        {
          "id": "bedroom"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
}],

"requestId": "XXXXXXX"
```

Answer (score 0):

There may have been some changes to how the execution is being sent. If you want to increase the temperature, and the mode is "cool", it would make sense that the thermostat should enter a "heat" mode.